# Mean Residual Life of Weibull Distribution closed form

Tags: probability, distributions, survival, reliability, weibull-distribution

Weibull distribution function is parameterized as $ F(x) = 1 - e^{(-(x/\sigma)^a)}$ and survival function is $S(x)= e^{(-(x/\sigma)^a)}$ where $a$ is shape parameter and $\sigma$ is the scale parameter.

Mean Residual Function is given by:

$mrl(x) = \frac{\int_{x}^{\infty} S(t) dt}{S(x)} = \frac{\int_{x}^{\infty} e^{(-(t/\sigma)^a)}dt}{e^{(-(x/\sigma)^a)}} $.

I can evaluate the above integral numerically. My question is there a closed form or any analytical form for above mean residual life $mrl(x)$ of Weibull distribution?

Comment: No, not in the usual meaning of closed form at least, since it involves an incomplete gamma.

Comment: @Glen_b, thanks. I have edited my question. Any analytical form would be good as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the interest of having an answer to your question, here's a derivation of an expression for the mean residual life in terms of an incomplete gamma function.

Use a substitution $u = (\frac{t}{\sigma})^a$.  Then $du = \frac{a}{\sigma} (\frac{t}{\sigma})^{a-1}dt$.

Since $\frac{t}{\sigma} = u^{1/a}$, this gives us $du = \frac{a}{\sigma} (u^{1/a})^{a-1}dt = \frac{a}{\sigma} u^{1-1/a}dt$, so that $dt = \frac{\sigma}{a} u^{1/a-1} du$.  Then

\begin{align*}mrl(x) &=  e^{{(x/\sigma)}^a} \int_{(x/\sigma)^a}^{\infty} \frac{\sigma}{a} u^{1/a-1} e^{-u} \, du \\ 
&= \frac{\sigma}{a} e^{{(x/\sigma)}^a} \Gamma\left(\frac{1}{a}, \left(\frac{x}{\sigma}\right)^a \right),
\end{align*}
where $\Gamma(s,x)$ is the [upper incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function).

This can be rewritten slightly by using a [recurrence property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Properties) of the upper incomplete gamma function:
\begin{align*}
mrl(x) &= \sigma e^{{(x/\sigma)}^a} \left(\Gamma\left(1 + \frac{1}{a}, \left(\frac{x}{\sigma}\right)^a \right) - \left(\left(\frac{x}{\sigma}\right)^a\right)^{1/a} e^{-{(x/\sigma)}^a} \right) \\
&= \sigma e^{{(x/\sigma)}^a} \Gamma\left(1 + \frac{1}{a}, \left(\frac{x}{\sigma}\right)^a \right) - x.
\end{align*}
The reader can decide which is simpler.

Neither of these expressions is closed-form in the usual sense, as noted in a comment above.  However, incomplete gamma functions are [implemented in some programming languages like Python](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.gammaincc.html#scipy.special.gammaincc).  Thus if your interest is numerical you could evaluate the MRL using one of these two expressions and calling that special function rather than using a more general numerical integration procedure.